# Can't use Jenkins downstream job current parameters when i trigger it from upstream job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a job trigger (upstream job) parametrized with [uno-choice dynamic choice parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74875956), to trigger a multiple jobs (downstream jobs).

trigger job parameters:

[image]

and i'm using this script that trigger selected jobs using the **post-build actions** -> **groovy post build**:

```
// param list of jobs to execute coming from upastream Job
def upstreamParam = "JOB_LIST_TRIGGER"
def upstreamParamFlag = "NEXT_RELEASE_TYPE"
def resolver = manager.build.buildVariableResolver
def JOBS_TO_EXECUTE = resolver.resolve(upstreamParam)
def FLAG = resolver.resolve(upstreamParamFlag )

def viewName = "test"
def jobsName = [] 

//only the NEXT RELEASE TYPE
def params = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('NEXT_RELEASE_TYPE_BIS', FLAG)

// if no job selected in the parameter, will trigger all jobs in the view "test", otherwise  will execute only selected jobs
if (JOBS_TO_EXECUTE == null || JOBS_TO_EXECUTE == ''){

    // retrieve jobs names from jenkins view
    hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView(viewName).items.each() {
           jobsName.push(it.getDisplayName())
    }

    // launch plugins jobs
        jobsName.each(){
          job = manager.hudson.getItem(it)
          cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(manager.build)
          def paramsAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(params)
          causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause)
          manager.hudson.queue.schedule(job, 0, causeAction, paramsAction)
       }
}else{

        // create a list of selected jobs in the JOB_LIST_TRIGGER param
    hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView(viewName).items.each() {
           if (JOBS_TO_EXECUTE.contains(it.getDisplayName())){
              jobsName.push(it.getDisplayName())
           }
    }

        // launch only job selected in the JOB_LIST_TRIGGER param
        jobsName.each(){
            job = manager.hudson.getItem(it)
            cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(manager.build)
            def paramsAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(params)
            causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause)
            manager.hudson.queue.schedule(job, 0, causeAction, paramsAction)
         }
}
```

in this code i only trigger **NEXT_RELEASE_PARAMETER** to the downstream jobs.

job1..job4 with below details to display the current job details.

```
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
# the current param
echo $RELEASE_VERSION
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
# the current param
echo $NEXT_RELEASE_TYPE
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
# the upstream param
echo $NEXT_RELEASE_TYPE_BIS
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
# the current param
echo $NEXT_RELEASE
echo "------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------"
```

the  output is:

```
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo

+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo

+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo Major
Major
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo

+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
+ echo ------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
```

the result prints only the upstream param but not the current parameters, so is there any way to get **downstream (job1..job4)** current parameters after it was triggred by **job-trigger**?

Comment: Hi, the plug-in used to be called uno-choice, but is now called Active Choices Plug-in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin

I haven't tried to reproduce your problem, but from what I understood, your problem is that the plug-in needs a HTML DOM to traverse the elements and find other parameter's values.

That's a limitation that we are currently discussing how best to fix it. Without the DOM, the plug-in returns a default value; normally the first value of the array returned by the Groovy script - if any - or an empty array in case of an error.

Comment: the plug-in doesn't return even the default value when i trigger the job from the upstream one... seems like i'm doing it the wrong way. Thanks @BrunoP.Kinoshita for your answer